# A good way to add mathematic formulas in XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I am creating an application at a company I am working with, and right now I an working with a "Mathematical tutorial program". In short, I need to create Silverlight applications (animations) with mathematic tutorials.

To solve this, I need to be able to create formulas. I need square root, fractions and alike!

I have been searching at Google and I have found loads of solutions.. But many seems really bad and inefficient.

I would prefer if I could have some tags like:

`<SquareRoot>9</SquareRoot>`, `<Fraction><Fraction.Upper>31</Fraction.Upper> ... </Fraction>`.

Or even:

```
<MathematicalObject>Latex syntax</MathematicalObject>
```

Problem is I need to have them a lot, and inserting random images or code behind magic, would really give problems.

**So: I am asking you clever people**:

What is the best and most efficient way to add mathematical formulas in XAML / Silverlight? If it could be really simple (and maybe even free?), it would be very nice!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general approach would be the following:

Create your own control. The content of that control will be interpreted as LaTeX code and converted into an image that is being displayed. You can use it like this:

```
<Grid>
    <my:YourLaTeXControl>LaTeX code</my:YourLaTeXControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yup - That was what I had in mind. I have also been searching for that solution, but how in the world would one do it?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Building your own control? Converting LaTeX to image?

Comment: Converting Latex to an image.. I guess you can use some third-party-magic?